# Cannot fetch a Firebase Realtime Database with anonymous authentication

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm building a React web app that looks to a JSON database through Firebase Realtime Database. Fetching the data works great with no authentication!

```
fetch('https://my-awesome-site.firebaseio.com/database.json')
        .then(res => {
            if(!res.ok) {
                throw Error('Could not fetch data for that resource, Captain.')
            }
            return res.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            setAwesomeData(data);
            setIsPending(false);
            setError(null);
            return data;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            setIsPending(false);
            setError(err.message);
        })
```

The rules for the Realtime Database were left as follows:

```
 {
  "rules": {
     ".read": "true",  
    ".write": "true"
  }
}
```

I am now trying to allow for anonymous authentication. I have enabled it through the 'Sign-in method' and added a function to my javascript to sign in anonymously and console log back the user.

```
const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(false);    

if (authenticated !== true) {
      firebase.app().auth().signInAnonymously()
        .then(() => {
          firebase.app().auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            if(user) {
              var uid = user.uid;
              console.log(uid);
            }
          })
        }).then(() => {
          setAuthenticated(true);
        }).catch((error) => {
          var errorCode = error.code;
          var errorMessage = error.message;
        });
      }
```

My Realtime Database rules are now:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

The anonymous user is created, however, I cannot fetch my data as before. Is there a step that I am missing with setting up the rules in Firebase or possibly in my javascript? Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you're signing in to Firebase Authentication in your code, you're then using the REST API to access Firebase's Realtime Database. The authentication information is not automatically passed to those REST calls (since the Firebase client doesn't know anything about the call), so your call to the database is unauthenticated and gets (correctly) rejected.

You'll either have to pass the authentication state yourself explicitly as explained in the Firebase documentation on [authenticating REST calls](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth?authuser=0#authenticate_with_an_id_token), or (much simpler) you can [use the Firebase Realtime Database SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start), which passes the information along automatically.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look more into these two methods and see what works!

Comment: I reached into grabbing data using the methods outlined in the Firebase Realtime Database SDK documentation. I got rid of my fetch calls. It works now. Thank you.